# PyCharm not detecting conda environments-Conda excutable is not found after manually choosing the path

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, interpreter, virtual-environment

Pycharm can not directly detect the conda environment. However, after I manually choose the python.exe, it still does not work.

[Manually choosing the environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9PAB.png)
[Still not excutable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuR7y.png)

I checked the path by

```
conda info --envs
```

,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFJVj.png). I just don't know why it does not work. :(

Comment: meybe  you need add python.exe  https://www.configserverfirewall.com/windows-10/add-python-to-path-windows-10/

Comment: Thank you so much! but I just added python.exe to the environment variables, but still does not help...

Comment: When you choose the Conda executable, it needs to be `conda.bat`, not `python.exe`.

Comment: Thank you! How should I check the path for `conda.bat`? I did not see it in the same folder of `python.exe`.

Comment: On my Windows setup it's `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat`. But of course it will vary according to your OS and how you installed Anaconda.

Comment: Thank you! but I find my `conda.bat`, but still it does not work.....

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I used the path to `conda.exe`, then I can choose my conda environment.